# The Hoeffding Inequality

Tags: probability

The modified Höffding Inequality provides a way to characterize the generalization error with a probabilistic bound
$$P [|E_{in}(g) − E_{out}(g)| > t] ≤ 2Me^{-2t^2N}$$
for any $t > 0$. If we set $t = 0.05$ and want the probability bound $2Me^{-2t^2N}$
to be at most $0.03$, what is the least number of examples $N$ (among the given choices) needed for the case $M = 1$?

[a] 500

[b] 1000

[c] 1500

[d] 2000

[e] More examples are needed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So, you put the values in the "equation", and then what happened? This question is so simple that it is hard to believe that you really tried anything yourself. In the end, the question is formulated in such a way that you don't even need to know about Hoeffding's inequality. You just have to substitute the given quantities into the given formula ($2M e^{-2t^2 N}$) and see whether the result is at most $0.03$, or not.